# Epub file reader in java swing

Tags: java, epub

I am using paul siegmann epub file reader for displaying the epub file in java swing application. But it has many problem like

1. CSS is not apply,
2. TOC problem in version 3,
3. No internal and external link listener, etc.

Could you pls guide me to other lib or how to fix those issues?

Comment: Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just unpack the EPUB (is a zip file), display the XHTML files with a browser control, and create a TOC tree by yourself using the content.opf/toc.ncx?